# What is measurement unit of life's duration used by Brahma?

Tags: brahma

As per the previous birth karma's, Brahma decides what will be duration of our life or how long we will live. My question is,Brahma uses which unit to decide our life time. For example: At current time our unit is year, hours, minutes etc. If we decide to do any work with in 
time limit then we decides something like this.. I will do this word in 1day/1hour/5 min.

But Brahma sure(as per me) don't use to follow humans year and hours unit to decide our life's duration. So which unit he uses to decides our life duration? Some says breath is the unit. How many breath we will take in our life is use to determine by Brahma. But my doubt here is that If we hold our breath, for ex. some yogas and tapas are there in which we need to hold our breath. So by doing
this our life time will get increase since we are taking long to complete our no. of predetermined breaths. And if someone breath fast (some people usually does) or takes short breaths then he/she actually shorting his/her life?

Comment: Whether Brahma uses breaths or not yo determine the life span, the control of breathing in Yoga is called 'Pranayama' or regulating Prana i.e.life and hence it maybe right If we hold our breath, our life time will get increased.

Comment: _"'Pranayama' or regulating Prana....  If we hold our breath, our life time will get increased"_ But our life time will increase because of benefits of Parnayama or coz of we are making delay in taking no. of our total breath? Or by both?

Comment: I think the benefits are derived from both, but the underlying principle is regulating the number of breaths we take.

Comment: If we consider "Brahma" as supreme "Jiva" (super-soul), then it lives only for 1 day/night. That *jiva* feels its 1 day/night exactly as how we feel our 1 day/night or an insect like "Mayfly" feels its 1 day/night. The difference here is that, Brahma's 1 day/night is equivalent to 1-1 Kalpa-s of humans (several Yuga-s) and 1-1 Kalpa-s of Mayfly is as good as 1 day/night of human. The other major difference is that, due to full of *Sattva*, Brahma repeats its 1 day/night immediately. So no deteriotation. However for humans & insects, the day/night changes to new day/night. Hence we deteriorate.

Comment: @iammilind I am not getting your point. 1 day or Brahma = 1 kalpa of human And 1 human day = 1 kalpa of Mayfly, Got that but what we got to learn from this info? Did I miss something? May be your comment exceeds my understanding capability because I am not that smart.

Comment: Qn is good. Above is just an answer-comment. Your lifespan is of several decades, while your skin cells have it only for 2-4 week. If "Rishabh" is identified as your full entirety, then it's life duration is several decades. But *jiva*s of your skin cells (life organisms) are also part of "Rishabh" & has life span of few weeks only! Now consider yourself as *Brahma* and various aspects of your body as other *jiva*s. You are the biggest *jiva*; body parts, skin, cell, DNA - are smaller and smaller *jiva*s. Depending on *jiva*, the life span is decided. In reality the whole universe is *Brahma*!

Comment: @iammilind You went so deep. I am only talking about time duration of wearing a body by any soul. How long(in which unit) a soul is allowed to wear a body? Different soul has different time duration as per their karma.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindu_units_of_time#For_Brahma